# Unable to attach and debug a Python script launched by ROS2

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, ros2

I have Visual Studio 2022 Professional with Python module installed.

If I start a Python script from a console, then open Visual Studio, attach the python.exe process, open the Python file, set a breakpoint, I see the breakpoint correctly setup, it gets reached, execution is stopped and then I can debug the script step by step.

Now, I'm using ROS2 humble. I run `ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker`, this ends up starting a Python interpreter running `<ros folder>\Lib\site-packages\demo_nodes_py\topics\talker.py`.

But then, when if attach this Python process in Visual Studio and open the `talker.py` file, I set a breakpoint, but it remains unresolved by Visual Studio (empty red circle) and execution never gets interrupted.

I added in the script a print of the process ID (`os.getpid()`) and the file path ((`str(Path( __file__ ).absolute())`), so I'm sure I attached the good process and opened the good file.

Is there anything in the environment that could make Visual Studio unable to resolve breakpoint and let me debug my app?